# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException occurred when changing access database manually

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, exception, datagridview

I have a C# project and an access database. Everything runs perfect but when I want to manually add a calculated field in the database and display it in a datagridview in C#, the `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` occurred and the program broke its execution.

**Error**

> Unrecognized database format Unrecognized database format

I tried to connect to database using `datagridview` Add Project Datasource wizard, in there when I want to test the connection still get me the same error.

I create a new database with same name and same tables without any data and the programs run, but when I copy only the fields name and data type in design view and want to start program I face with the same error.

Suggestions in this regard will be helpful

Comment: So, what did you *do* (in terms of code) when you wanted to "...manually add a calculated field in the database and display it in a datagridview in C#" ?

Comment: It seems your database field type and code field type not match

Comment: @MarcGravell  I do nothing, I have a data adapter that select * from table and put them into a data table, and I set data table to data source of datagridview, when the data adapter want to fill data table this error accorred

Comment: I have to say that in the past i face with this problem without no reason, all I had to do for solving it was:
create a new database, copy all of data from old database to new one, delete old database and rename new database to my old database name, but this time it couldn't help

Comment: @SandipPatel I tried to connect to database using datagridview wizard, in there when I want to test the connection still get me the same error:
Unrecognized database format

Comment: Are you able to execute select statement on that table?

Comment: @SandipPatel I think so, because the error occurred when the data adapter wants to fill data table:

string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryconnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
            OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from SelectedFeeds", Connection);
            DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
the error show in this line:
            **DataA.Fill(DTable);**

Comment: @SandipPatel I don't know what's wrong with my ms-access
I create a new database with same name and same tables without any data and the programs run,
but when I copy only the fields name and data type in design view and want to start program I face with the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally

I changed my `ms-access` from 2016 to 2013 and create a new `database` and then past my data to new `database` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

There you can get your OldeDB Number...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator.getelements.aspx

You must use your Number to connect successfully

Comment: can you explain it to me a little more please?

Comment: Create a Console Application.

Use this code (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator.getelements.aspx)
and start console.

Copy your OdeDB Version (my is Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0) and paste it in your source